# Replacing HTML image names with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm looking for solution to replace part of the image URL with pure JavaScript but regex is giving me headaches. The page loads dynamically normal size "_S2" images. However I'd like to switch all images to bigger "_S3" versions.
How do I Switch all page image names from _S2 to _S3 with JS?

```
<body>
<script>

</script>
<img src="0330907_PE520866_S2.JPG"  />
<img src="0349454_PE535816_S2.JPG"/>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you post your tries? (the code you already came up with)

Comment: Tip : don't put `<script>` tag before HTML body content, it leads to slow the loading of your page.

Comment: @Zeratops it will also be executed *before* your DOM has fully loaded if used without a `window.load` or a `$(function() { ... })`

Answer (score 4):

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i in imgs) {
    imgs[i].src = imgs[i].src.replace("_S2", "_S3");
}
```

Easy and without regexp, and without jquery.

Answer (score 2):

Use `replace`

[**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/to0t6k7L/)

1. Select all the images whose `src` ends with `_S2.JPG` using selector `img[src$="_S2.JPG"]` and `querySelectorAll`
2. Loop over images and replace `_S2` by `_S3` from the image source and update the `src` value.

**Code:**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    var images = document.querySelectorAll('img[src$="_S2.JPG"]');

    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        images[i].src = images[i].src.replace('_S2', '_S3');
    }
});
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors for selectors.

Comment: Hi, this seems to work great! However I noticed that the script needs to be inserted after the images to get it work. How to implement the code to load after images if I have no access to the footer section of the page because of CMS-system? I have also troubles to target the change to div id "imgThmProduct". <img id="imgThmProduct" src="0332761_PE522162_S2.JPG" border="0" alt="This is test image" class="prodImg"/>

Comment: @Teme Wrap the code in [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) or [onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load) or move the script to the end of `<body>`

Comment: DOMContentLoaded worked correctly! I appreciate for your prompt help!

Answer (score 1):

Get all images and use replace for each image:

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    var image = images[i];
    image.src = image.src.replace('_S2', '_S3');
}
```